# Google MyMaps not appearing on safari iPad

Tags: google-maps, ipad, safari

I have an embedded Google MyMap on my website (in an iFrame) and it doesn't appear in Safari on iPad (just a blank space). I've tested it on an iPhone and it works on that.

I was wondering if this is a known issue? Has anyone else experienced it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you share the Maps as public? it is working for me for the follow fiddle, which is just a:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=zEqPWjt6j01c.kwDfQcqJ5G2U" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/2s2qgd62/embedded/result/](https://goo.gl/tPVlFH)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Map didn't show on ipad on safari, but was working fine on firefox on my iPad.
I solved it by resetting privacy and location settings on my iPad